# How to select two SUMs from one table but one SUM must be made from only max. data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
Room       Papers    Pens
1           30        30
3           10        10
4           15        15
4           35        25
3           25        5
2           15        45
2           5         15
4           7         8
4           11        9
4           12        11
1           8         8
```

I need to get SUM(Papers) for Rooms 2,4 which I know how to get (it will be together 100) but then I need also get in this query SUM(Pens) also for Rooms 2,4 BUT only for highest value for each Room. It will be for Room 2 value 45 and for Room 4 value 25 in this table and SUM must be 70.

I have used this code but ofcourse it is not working correct for Pens value...

```
SELECT SUM(Papers) AS Papers, SUM(DISTINCT Pens) AS Pens FROM MyTable
WHERE (Room = '2' OR Room = '4')
```

THX for help

Comment: Why 173? It is 100.

Comment: I am sorry. Yep SUM is 100 for these two rooms... My bad

Comment: It seems like an implausible scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Papers) AS Papers, 
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM MyTable 
        WHERE Room = m.Room AND Pens > m.Pens 
      ) THEN 0 
      ELSE Pens 
    END 
  ) AS Pens
  FROM MyTable m
WHERE (Room = '2' OR Room = '4')
```

Comment: THX for reply but please can you tell me what exactly is that m.Room? Why you have add m. before Room and also before Pens and then you are calling m again after MyTable

Comment: `m` is an alias of table `MyTable`. Inside the subquery I need to have another *copy* of `MyTable` and this `m` distinguishes the *copy* that is used outside the subquery with the one used inside the subquery.

Comment: @daniel if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by ticking the checkmark at the left.